# Taking month and year from column and showing last date of the month and year

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-date-functions

So i have 2 column Year and Month and I want to take the month and the year to show in the new column and showing the last date of the month

Example :
Year column = 2019, 2020, 2021
Month Column = Jan, Feb, Mar

i want the result : 31-01-2019, 29-02-2019, etc

Comment: Have you read the docs on date and time functions? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Try LAST_DAY() function: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day

Comment: i have read those, im confused how to extract the month with MON format and the year from the column, and then putting those together with the last day of the month, since I'm new to SQL. i hope you can help me thanks!

Comment: Could use 12 `replace` statements for that.. e.g. `replace(replace(month, 'Jan', '01'), 'Feb', '02'))`

Comment: so i need to replace all the month first to digit? after that I use the last day function ??

Answer (score 2):

First concatenate the year, the month and `'01'` to create a string date like:`'2019-Jan-01'`.
Then use `STR_TO_DATE()` to convert it to a valid date and finally use `LAST_DAY()` to get the last day of that year/momth:

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(year, '-', month, '-01'), '%Y-%b-%d')) date
FROM tablename
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b4bd856382e2200abe13d2ee859b9a59).

Comment: if the month and year data are in a huge amount, I need to change them 1 by 1 into string? Example : I have data from January 2019 until January 2021

Comment: @Michael No. In the function concat() all numeric years will be implicitly converted to strings.

Comment: @Michael: No. *You* write just one query that contains the one conversion expression as shown. The *DBMS* will then apply this expression on every row in the table.

Comment: `LAST_DAY(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(TAHUN, '-', BULAN, '-01'), '%Y-%b-%d')) date AS  PERIODE`

 i got error when i want to rename the header to PERIODE

Comment: @Michael: I used `date` for the alias. Remove it.

Comment: `00909. 00000 -  "invalid number of arguments"` im getting this error

Comment: @Michael this is not a MySql error. I don't know how you use my query.